# Generation of designer file failed: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80042929

Tags: asp.net

What does the following error mean?

Geeneration of designer file failed: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80042929

It started showing up in my application when building and I'm not sure what's causing it.  I'm using VS.Net 2008 and .Net 3.5

Comment: I've seen this once before as well, though I cannot for the of me recall what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you suffering from either of the issues in [this forum post](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2514240&SiteID=1)?

Comment: That link no longer goes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For If this error occuers while you add a file/folder or something to a form then recheck the name of the file/folder it must be pre-existing.